# Uncertain about model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, associations

I'm working on a project that allows a user to create a company. If a user creates a company, the user will be the admin.

However I would also like that user to then be able to invite users to sign up. So that all the users will belong to that company.

So my question is that the company would technically I guess belong_to the admin. However the company also has many users.

What would be the right association setup for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both a `belongs_to` and `has_many` relation to `User` from your `Company` model at the same time. Set an alias to separate them like this:

```
# app/models/company.rb
belongs_to :admin, :class_name => 'User'
has_many :users
```

Now you can access the admin user through `@company.admin` and the users through `@company.users`.

Comment: then it'll be admin_id instead of user_id I presume as a column name?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Company

belongs_to :admin, :class_name => 'User', foreign_key: :admin_id
has_many :users

end
```

This should work. When creating the Company model, give

```
admin_id = @current_user.id
```

@current_user provided you are using Devise for authentication management.

Cheers,

Akhil